# Dynamic url not generated currently for lat and Long android

Tags: android, android-location

I have generated `Current location` value and i am passing it to the URL dynamically. I am getting value of `Latitude` and 'Longitude' in my Logcat. but dynamic URl for `LatLongUrl` is not generated currently.

```
Log.d(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()),"Latitude");
                    Log.d(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()),"Longitude");


                //urlJsonObj = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=21.2150756,72.8880545&radius=500&type=hospital&key=AIzaSyBldIefF25dfjjtMZq1hjUxrj4T4hK66Mg";

                urlJsonObj = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()+","+String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()+"&radius=500&type=hospital&key=AIzaSyBldIefF25dfjjtMZq1hjUxrj4T4hK66Mg";
                Log.d(urlJsonObj,"LatLongUrl");
```

Logcat displaying as bellow in which value of Latitude and 'Longitude' generated but dynamic URl for `LatLongUrl` is not generated currently.

```
    04-20 15:00:45.477 3209-3209/com.example.chaitanya.nearbyplace D/21.225225225225223: Latitude
04-20 15:00:45.477 3209-3209/com.example.chaitanya.nearbyplace D/72.8905100797212: Longitude

                                                                                   [ 04-20 15:00:45.477  3209: 3209 D/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=21.225225225225223&radLatLongUrl
```

**Updated quetion**

i have update code as bellow. but its still not generateed URL properly.

```
        String Latitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
                String Longitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());

   urlJsonObj = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+Latitude+","+Longitude+"&radius=500&type="+TypeName+"&key=AIzaSyBldIefF25dfjjtMZq1hjUxrj4T4hK66Mg";
                Log.d(urlJsonObj,"LatLongUrl");
```

in Logcat

```
     [ 04-20 15:24:57.826 23415:23415 D/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=21.225225225225223,72.LatLongUrl
```

Comment: declare  the String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()) and String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude() and use String format to generate URL.

Comment: first set  hardcoded location value in your lJsonObject and check weather it is coming or not!

Comment: i have do the same. but its still generate broker URL.  @Sajithv

Comment: Since you're concatenating strings, you don't have to explicitly do `String.valueOf()`. Use `URL.parse()`. Add parentheses accordingly.

Comment: What's the Log after updating the URL

Comment: @MaharithAdityaSS i have update quetion. and displaing the Logcat

Comment: @alka please check my updated answer. It might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your line with this

```
 String urlJsonObj = 
 "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" + 
 new BigDecimal(mLastLocation.getLatitude()).toString() + "," + 
 new BigDecimal(mLastLocation.getLongitude()).toString() + 
 "&radius=500&type=hospital&key=AIzaSyBldIefF25dfjjtMZq1hjUxrj4T4hK66Mg";
```

Comment: Parenthesis are not properly coded. (Assuming the given code snippet in question is same as used in code)

Answer (score 0):

I think your Parenthesis after String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()) and String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()) 
is missing

```
String urlJsonObj = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude())+","+String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude())+"&radius=500&type=hospital&key=AIzaSyBldIefF25dfjjtMZq1hjUxrj4T4hK66Mg";
```

That's in your log

[ 04-20 15:00:45.477  3209: 3209 D/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=21.225225225225223&radLatLongUrl

it's like this

Answer (score 0):

```
 String latitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        String longitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude())
        String urlJsonObj =String.format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?" +
                "location=%s,%s &radius=500&type=hospital&key=AIzaSyBldIefF25dfjjtMZq1hjUxrj4T4hK66Mg",latitude,longitude);
```

This will helps you to resolve problem.